# D3DXLoadSurfaceFromMemory + GDI+: How to Show Image?

Tags: c++, directx, gdi+

I would like to load an image previously loaded using GDI+ into Direct X; is it possible? I know that I can save the image to disk and then load it using:

```
D3DXLoadSurfaceFromFile
```

But I would like to use

```
D3DXLoadSurfaceFromMemory
```

with the GDI+ image loaded in memory; the GDI+ image is a *GdiPlus*::Image type.

I'm using Visual C++ 2010.

Thanks in advance.

**Update:**

```
using namespace Gdiplus;
std::string decodedImage = base64_decode(Base64EncodedImage); 
DWORD imageSize = decodedImage.length();
HGLOBAL hMem = ::GlobalAlloc(GMEM_MOVEABLE, imageSize);
LPVOID pImage = ::GlobalLock(hMem);
memcpy(pImage, decodedImage.c_str(), imageSize);
IStream* pStream = NULL;
::CreateStreamOnHGlobal(hMem, FALSE, &pStream);
Image image(pStream);
```

The above pice of code let me transform an image encoded in base64 (**Base64EncodedImage**) to a GDI+ image; so far so good, next I convert the image as a byte array (**buffer**):

```
int stride = 4 * ((image.GetWidth() + 3) / 4);
    size_t safeSize = 
    stride * image.GetHeight() * 4 + sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER) + 
    sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER) + 256 * sizeof(RGBQUAD);
HGLOBAL mem = GlobalAlloc(GHND, safeSize);
LARGE_INTEGER seekPos = {0};
ULARGE_INTEGER imageSizeEx;
HRESULT hr = pStream->Seek(seekPos, STREAM_SEEK_CUR, &imageSizeEx); 
BYTE* buffer = new BYTE[imageSizeEx.LowPart];
hr = pStream->Seek(seekPos, STREAM_SEEK_SET, 0);    
hr = pStream->Read(buffer, imageSizeEx.LowPart, 0);
```

As a side note, I can save the byte array to disk as a png image with no loss, and then load it using **D3DXLoadSurfaceFromFile**.

Next I create and load the surface:

```
hr = d3ddevex->CreateOffscreenPlainSurface(image.GetWidth(), image.GetHeight(), D3DFMT_X8R8G8B8, D3DPOOL_SYSTEMMEM, &surf, NULL);

RECT srcRect;  
srcRect.left = 0;   
srcRect.top = 0;  
srcRect.bottom = image.GetWidth();  
srcRect.right = image.GetHeight();

hr = D3DXLoadSurfaceFromMemory(surf, NULL, NULL, buffer, D3DFMT_X8R8G8B8,image.GetWidth(), NULL, &srcRect,D3DX_FILTER_NONE,0);
```

This IS working, BUT the image appears all disordered, colored pixels everywhere but not a "readable" image at all (like if it were a test pattern from an arcade game).

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to identify a suitable DirectX texture format (e.g. DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32A32_UINT) so that the DirectX texture can receive the data from the GDI+ without modification. You can copy the data in using ID3D11DeviceContext::CopyResource() or equivalent in whatever version of DirectX you're using.
To draw the image you'll need to set up some geometry (triangles) that form a quad and pass this to the pipeline (Google "fullscreen quad" for more detail).

Comment: Hi thanks for your anwser but apply as a texture is not what I'm looking for. So far, I've been able to convert the GDI+ Image to a BYTE* array; and then pass it to the function: `D3DXLoadSurfaceFromMemory(surf, NULL, NULL, buffer, D3DFMT_X8R8G8B8,image.GetWidth(), NULL, &srcRect,D3DX_FILTER_NONE,0);` being `buffer` the buffer containing the image data (a png file streamed from the web). But I'm getting the following error: **Access violation at 0x00ed0000** , so I'm stuck there.

Comment: I've been able to load the image and show it in screen. But all the pixels are messy, not in order it seems; I guess it could be D3DFMT_X8R8G8B8 parameter?

Comment: Probably. Are you using the debug output from DirectX to assist your trouble-shooting? You can enable it in the DirectX Control Panel. The output is to the VisualStudio console window. It's usually very informative (although it sounds like you're past that).

Comment: I'm going to check that out. I've been told to use `IDirect3DSurface9->LockRect` so I'm going to see how it goes.

Answer (score 0):

The SrcPicht parameter si img.GetWidth()*4, it's in bytes:

```
hr = D3DXLoadSurfaceFromMemory(
    spSurface,
    NULL,
    &rectDes, 
    bd.Scan0, 
    D3DFMT_X8R8G8B8,
    image.GetWidth()*4, //@ here is different only
    NULL, 
    &rectSrc,
    D3DX_FILTER_NONE,0);
```

I tested, it worked.